# Create pandas dataframe from a dictionary of series

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary of 68 keys whereby each key has a list with 50 values in it. For example, my dict is the following, whereby each series has 50 values in it, e.g. value1, value2....

```
key1 : Series1
key2 : Series2
 .   :  .
key50:  Series50
```

I now want to make the following dataframe out of the dictionary:

```
key1          key2
value1      value1
 .            .
 .            .
value50     value 50
```

I looked at other threads and tried the following command:

```
df= pd.DataFrame([dict])
```

However, this yields:

```
key1          key2
Series1       Series2
```

How doI get the values in the dataframe instead of the Series. In the end, I should get dataframe sized 50*68.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass `dict_` directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
```

Also, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's bad form, and it shadows the builtin class with the same name.

Comment: Sometimes I think too much. Unpacking a single element list is nothing but passing it directly ;).

Comment: @Bharathshetty I thought to correct you, but I was itching to write an answer.. :-)

Comment: Nowadays very less pandas questions.

Comment: thank you guys. I realized I had different indices for the several series. I resetted the indices and then it worked like a charm. :) Thanks!

Comment: `it shadows the builtin` this will leads to  'dict' object is not callable. I faced it a lot of times.

Comment: @FriedrichFranz That would've been the next issue, had you solved this one... :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is this a duplicated?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263897/how-to-reassign-dict-functionality-back-to-the-dict

Answer (score 1):

unpacking the list might help i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame(*[dict])
```

If you have dict of series like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[2,5,1,1,5,1]})
data = {'A' : df['A'], 'B' : df['B']}
```

Then

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(*[data])
```

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  5
2  3  1
3  4  1
4  5  5
5  6  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with something similar, I have a dictionary of pd.Series. I want the dictionary keys to be the index and the series index to be the column names:

```
dic ={0: pd.Series([0.1,0.2,0.3],index=['a','b','c']), 1: pd.Series([1.1,1.2,1.3], index=['a','b','c'])}

dic

Out[21]: 
{0: a    0.1
 b    0.2
 c    0.3
 dtype: float64,
 1: a    1.1
 b    1.2
 c    1.3
 dtype: float64}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic).T

df

Out[23]: 
     a    b    c
0  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3
```

I think the solution to your problem is just without the .T?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df
Out[4]: 
     0    1
a  0.1  1.1
b  0.2  1.2
c  0.3  1.3
```