# How to reassign dict functionality back to the 'dict'?

Tags: python

I accidentally assigned a dictionary to the keyword `dict`, now its leading to `dict object not callable`. So how can I reassign back the functionality without restarting the kernel?

Comment: `del dict` should work?

Comment: Yep... this is a dupe (since you asked).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you are really good at finding duplicates. :-)

Comment: That does not mean it isn't a good question. Some duplicates should be asked  to allow users to find the same target through different search term.

Comment: @Bharathshetty slight aside, are you aware of [this](https://sopython.com/canon/) which can help. This dupe isn't in the list, but it can be handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict` is a builtin. **Builtins are grouped together in the `builtin` package**. So you can use:

```
import builtins
dict = builtins.dict
```

A piece of advice is to **never override builtins**: do not assign to variables named `list`, `dict`, `set`, `int`, `float`, etc.

That being said, you can **remove `dict` from the scope** as well. In that case Python will *fallback* on the builtins. So you **delete the variable**:

```
temp_dict = dict
del dict  # remove the `dict`, now it will delegate to the `dict` builtin
```

For example:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict
{}
>>> del dict
>>> dict
<class 'dict'>
```

So you delete it out of the scope, and then Python will again bind it to the "outer" scope.

Comment: Yes I will never do that. It was bugging me from a long time so I asked it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to override the key words in Python.

If you want you dict back, use this:

```
from builtins import dict
d = dict()
```

But this codes will override your defined dict again. So you can use the following codes to control the scope:

```
dict = lambda: 'damn it, I override the buildins'

d = dict()
print(d)

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def get_dict_back():
    import builtins
    yield builtins.dict


with get_dict_back() as build_dict:
    d = build_dict({'a': 1})
    print(d)

print(dict())
```

The buildin dict is only avaiable in the with-statement.

Output:

```
damn it, I override the buildins
{'a': 1}
damn it, I override the buildins
```

Comment: It seems counter intuitive to do this, because there's already an existing variable called "dict" you don't want to shadow that as well. Keeping it within it's namespace would be better.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are right, I'll make it better.

Comment: @MenglongLi though I felt `Willem Van Onsem`'s much simpler.

Comment: @Bharathshetty No kidding, in my post, I provide both ways and claims the side-effect.