# Assign Value in builtin function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, built-in

I am using Pandas(python).I want to write this line

```
a=pd.Series([1,2,3])
```

But bymistake I write it as

```
a=pd.Series=[1,2,3]
```

When I write correct syntax it gives error

```
ba=pd.Series([1,2,3])
```

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Because it assign list `pd.Series` =`[1, 2, 3]`

```
>>> pd.Series
[1, 2, 3]
```

How to remove this list from `pd.Series`?

Comment: I think simpliest is restart your IDE, e.g. spyder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple re-assign `pd.Series` to the correct value:

```
pd.Series = pd.core.series.Series
```

This only works if there is a reference to the original function/class still around (in this case there is `pd.core.series.Series`). In case you overwrite something that isn't references somewhere else this won't work.

Just to give another example (based on a question in the comments), suppose you overwrote `list`, you can use the `builtins` module (or the `__builtin__` module in Python 2):

```
list = [1,2,3]          # overwritten list
b = list(range(10))     # throws a "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

import builtins
list = builtins.list    # restored
b = list(range(10))     # works
```

However often it's much easier to restart the Python interpreter (which should also work) and in some cases it might only be the only option (in case nothing else references the overwridden value.

Comment: For me this problem happens with built-in `list`. What can I do? `list = list`? what do you think?

Comment: `list = builtins.list` (after importing the [builtins module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)).

Comment: @jezrael you could see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263897/how-to-reassign-dict-functionality-back-to-the-dict

Answer (score 2):

Use the [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) buildin function to reload the module.

```
reload(pd)
```

Showcase:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> pd.Series=[1,2,3]
>>> pd.Series
[1, 2, 3]
>>> reload(pd)
<module 'pandas' from '.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc'>
>>> pd.Series
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: `reload` is python 2 only, so this won't work on Python 3 (and the question has a Python 3 tag). However you can use importlib (or similar) for an equivalent function.

Comment: You are right. I missed that. [importlib.reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-nameerror-name-reload-is-not-defined) is indeed the python3 equivalent.