# How to map list of strings containing key value to dict in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

My list contains the following elements:

```
>>> s = "foo a=b c=d e=f"
>>> s.split()
['set', 'a=b', 'c=d', 'e=f']
>>> splitted = s.split()
>>> splitted[1:]
['a=b', 'c=d', 'e=f']
```

Now I want to use map to get the following result:

```
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

I tried the following, but this gives me an IndexError:

```
>>> map(lambda x : dict((a[0], a[1]) for a in x.split('=')) , splitted[1:])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. Also, there are several indexing operations, which of them raises the exception?

Comment: Why are you indexing from 1? python is zero index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to iterate over what you've split, just wrap that in an iterable, like a tuple:

```
>>> splitted
['a=b', 'c=d', 'e=f']
>>> [dict((x.split('='),)) for x in splitted]
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

I.E.

```
(x.split('='),)
```

Is a tuple with one element, the result of `.split`ing on the `'='` sign.

Or using `map` and `lambda`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: dict((x.split('='),)), splitted))
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

I will say, this seems like a rather un-useful data-structure.

To be clear, your construction fails because you are iterating too deeply. The generator expression:

```
(a[0], a[1]) for a in x.split('=')
```

Is iterating over `x.split('=')`, which in this case is always a list with two elements, length-1 strings, e.g. `['a','b']`.

Comment: Your second method raise error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` on python 3.x, can you confirm?

Comment: @GarbageCollector no, it doesn't, you probably have done `dict = <some_dict_literal>` somewhere in your interpreter session/script

Answer (score 1):

You may create a simple list comprehension to achieve this. Here you need to split each string based on `=` and type-cast it to `dict`. For example:

```
>>> my_list = ['a=b', 'c=d', 'e=f']

>>> [dict([my_str.split('=')])  for my_str in my_list]
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

---

Here's the working working version of your solution using *lambda*:

```
#     actually you don't need to iterate here v
>>> list(map(lambda x : dict([[a for a in x.split('=')]]) , my_list))
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

This could be simplified as:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x : dict([x.split('=')]) , my_list))
[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

Comment: Your second and third method raise error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` on python 3.x, can you confirm?

Comment: @GarbageCollector It works for me. I am using Python 3.4.1

Comment: Yes sorry about this, I think there was some naming conflict in my python shell. Works perfectly.

Comment: @GarbageCollector take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263897/how-to-reassign-dict-functionality-back-to-the-dict

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip function:

```
result= list(map(lambda x: dict(zip(*x.split('='))) ,splitted[1:]))
```

OR

```
needed = list(dict(zip(*x.split('='))) for x in splitted[1:])
```